# Euclid's Proof of XI-22 is Incorrect.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Proposition 22 in Book XI of Euclid's Elements states that "If there are three plane angles such that the sum of any two is greater than the remaining one, and they are contained by equal straight lines, then it is possible to construct a triangle out of the straight lines joining the ends of the equal straight lines.".

In essence, this means that given 3 isosceles triangles whose equal sides equivalent in all 3 and with the property that the sum of two of the angles is greater than the remaining one; then the unequal side of the remaining angle is also smaller than the sum of the unequal sides of the other two.

Euclid's proof goes through the following construction, which transposes one of the angles to the side of another: [image]
From it, we clearly see that the segment $HJ$ is greater than $BC$ because $\angle HGJ > \angle BAC$, and , therefore, $HI + IJ > HJ > BC$.

The problem, however, is that this construction does not work if $\angle HGI + \angle IGJ > \pi$: [image] If that is the case, then we cannot say that $\angle HGJ = \angle HGI + \angle IGJ$ and, therefore, the construction is invalid.

I have tried to find answers about this, but there seems to be barely any content regarding even prop. 22 itself - and nothing about this inconsistency. Can somebody help?

Comment: As a reference: https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookXI/propXI22.html

Comment: The construction detailed in that link is exactly the one I have showed. It does not hold true in the case that the sum of two of the angles is larger than $\pi$ (look at the second image)

Comment: I was posting for that who didn't have Euclid's Elements on hand as a direct reference. That said: the proof begins from the premise that "there are three plane angles such that the sum of any two is greater than the remaining one." But the case you're considering has the obtuse angle larger than the two acute angles together, and seems thus outside the scope of the proposition.

Comment: Doesn't the proposition hold true even if we're talking about the sums of measures of the angles (i.e. the second construction still applies?). I'm not sure if I'm looking for a problem where there is none, but this proof makes no sense if $\angle BAC = 160 ^{\circ}$, $\angle EDF = 150 ^{\circ}$, $\angle HGI = 120 ^{\circ}$, for example

Comment: I think you are right, but Euclid's proof is flawed for a deeper reason: he never proved that if each of three segments is less than the sum of the other two then you can construct a triangle with them. See note at the previously linked page.